# MPMoviePlayerController and next button

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to use MPMovieplayerController has a playlist player.
so my question is did you success to acheive this ?

How to catch when user clicks on next button ?

I tried MoviePlayer from apple sample code, in order to add overlay, but it does not help for he next button.

thanks for your help.

Thierry

** my sanwer **

I can't
The only way is to hide QT controls and add an overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, see my question and answer.

[How can I know users click fast forward and fast rewind buttons on the playback controls in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593683/how-can-i-know-users-click-fast-forward-and-fast-rewind-buttons-on-the-playback-c/3598383#3598383)